# Different constraints on iPhone 7 plus and other iPhones

Tags: uitableview, autolayout, constraints, ios-autolayout, size-classes

I'm using UiTableView with static cell's and right detail table view cell style and I found that on all iPhone's except iPhone 7 plus leading space to left label equals 16 and on iPhone 7 plus it equals 20.
Screenshots of same cell in different iPhones: [image]

[image]

I need to create custom cell with label that must have same leading spacing and I thought I can use size classes for it, but how if all iPhones have regular height and compact width in portrait mode (app use only portrait mode). I know that this problem can be solved programmatically, but there is must be some way to solve it via interface builder.
Screenshots of my custom cell and right detail style cell on iPhone 7 plus (my custom cell at the top have leading constraint equals 16, but it have to be 20 for 7 plus): 
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the margin of the top level view, which is set by the system to the values you described. You can override the margins of the view to be the same on all devices.

Comment: Thank's for answer, I tried this code - cell.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 16, bottom: 0, right: 0) and i found that it can't be less than 20.

Comment: Margins are hierarchical and the top level view has the margins you don’t want. I’m not where I can try it out, but if I remember correctly, you can’t change the top level margins, but you can set preservesSuperviewLayoutMargins to false.